# code javascript results to localhost:xxxx:

Tags: javascript

This code uses an api and when you run the .js from the node console with node it works well and shows the requests of the api in the console.

I need to show me the results by server `localhost:xxxx` on a page and I do not know what I have to modify or add to the code.

Please someone can help me, I am very new and I would appreciate the addition of the necessary code lines.

```
const binance = require('../node-binance-api.js');

binance.prices(function(error, ticker) {    
    console.log("prices()", ticker);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a route (and it would be really easy if us you Express.js for that) to show results on a page.
For example,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/',(request,response)=>{
binance.prices(function(error, ticker) {    
    res.send("prices()", ticker);
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a fantastic solution. It has worked very well for me. a greeting

Comment: No problem! Happy to help